# Link to a GitHub milestone by its name

Tags: github, milestone

I'd like to link to GitHub milestones by their name. We have milestones named by version numbers, e.g. `0.1.0`, `0.1.1`, `0.2.0`... but milestones URLs have internal numbers (https://github.com/owner/project/milestone/1, https://github.com/owner/project/milestone/2, ...). How can I automatically generate a link to the corresponding milestone URL given only its milestone name?

Comment: `[whatever you want](actual link)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I clarified my question: the actual links should be *generated automatically* based on the milestone name.

Comment: The auto linking on GitHub is described [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls). Milestones aren't covered.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my question is not limited to links in GitHub Markdown syntax. If neither GitHub nor third-party services provide such linking capability, it's probably possibly by using the GitHub API

Comment: So what is the scope? Have you tried using the API? What happened?

Comment: I have not tried the API but I would accept a detailled answer that explains how to use the API for this use case. I asked because I hoped there was another method such as a special kind of URL template provided by GitHub or by another service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no official way or third-party service to link to a GitHub milestone by its name but it would be easy to build such service based on GitHub API. As indicated by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), the [milestones API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/milestones/) can be used to query all milestones and then find a corresponding link. Given user `$USER`, repository name `$REPO` and milestone name `$VERSION`, this one-line gets the milestone URL (requires `curl` and `jq`):

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/milestones?per_page=100' \
  | jq -r ".[]|select(.title==\"$VERSION\").html_url"
```

This only works for up to 100 milestones because of API response pagination.